# chaos-mesh installation on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, docker, kubernetes

I am trying to install chaos-mesh on my CentOS 7 machine but I encounter some difficulties:

```
2022-11-25T14:53:30.795Z    ERROR   chaos-daemon.daemon-server  chaos-daemon/main.go:94 build chaos-daemon server   
{
    "error": "create daemon server: failed to dial \"/host-run/containerd.sock\": context deadline exceeded: connection error: desc = \"transport: error while dialing: dial unix:///host-run/containerd.sock: timeout\"",
    "errorVerbose": "failed to dial \"/host-run/containerd.sock\": context deadline exceeded: connection error: desc = \"transport: error while dialing: dial unix:///host-run/containerd.sock: timeout\"\ncreate daemon server\ngithub.com/chaos-mesh/chaos-mesh/pkg/chaosdaemon.BuildServer\n\t/home/runner/work/chaos-mesh/chaos-mesh/pkg/chaosdaemon/server.go:213\nmain.main\n\t/home/runner/work/chaos-mesh/chaos-mesh/cmd/chaos-daemon/main.go:92\nruntime.main\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:250\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1594"
}
```

Could You help me out indicate what I am doing wrong?

I use:
k3s version v1.25.3+k3s1 (f2585c16)
Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57

k3s server works with `--docker` flag and `--write-kubeconfig-mode=644`

I install chaos-mesh, using:

```
curl -sSL https://mirrors.chaos-mesh.org/latest/install.sh | bash -s -- --k3s
```